# Could mass production of guns be possible by slaves?

Tags: economy, empire-building, slavery, guns

I'm imagining a setting with 16<sup>th</sup>-17<sup>th</sup> century tech level. In this era, there's the rise of guns and blackpowder, and slavery too.

Slavery was used mostly for agricultural reasons, but there were a few with artisanal skills.

Imagine an empire that wants to mass produce guns in order to wage war and trade for more slaves. In this empire, some wealthy individuals made a contract: if the empire gave them slaves, they could mass produce guns.

The guns produced might require the least skill possible. Gunsmithing is an art, like blacksmithing and woodworking. I don't thingk you could get any slave to make a flintlock, but maybe a simpler lock: a matchlock.

I could imagine too, that this practice lower the prices of guns.

So, what do you think? **Is possible to mass produce guns with slave labor?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In that time period, firearms (and every other complex product) were handcrafted by an artisan. It was certainly possible to train slaves as artisans, but you had to treat them nearly as well as free laborers to get a similar quality product. Also, having dozens or hundreds of *artisans* working in parallel does not reduce the unit cost appreciably. Finally, teaching slaves how to make firearms this way seems likely to be bad for your health.

Mass production, which means *unskilled* labor producing high volumes of identical standardized parts, or assembling same, is what will deliver the cost reduction you are looking for. More importantly, you don’t need to train factory workers much or treat them well, so disposable wage slaves will be cheaper than your valuable chattel slaves. And since the product process is distributed across hundreds of workers who only know one tiny piece, and they can’t follow it without your factory and tools anyway, there is little risk of them making guns of their own on the side.

This change was a distinct (and enormous) step on the tech tree, which unfortunately had not yet arrived (at least in the West) in your time period. The first mass-produced firearm with interchangeable parts was made by Eli Whitney in 1798, just a few years after his (in)famous cotton gin and roughly the same time as the idea was applied to thousands of other products.

Could a time traveler from our time pull it off? Probably. But if so, the idea would be copied and applied to literally every field, moving the start of the Industrial Revolution forward to whatever time period they arrived in—and all the social and economic changes that came with it, both good and bad.

Comment: The guns aren't much danger without ammo.

Comment: @Mary Ammo is easy. Powder is more difficult.

Comment: @Mary You’d need factories mass-producing ammo for the guns, and it’s much easier to steal and smuggle.

Comment: For post Industrial Revolution example - for example Nazi Germany employed slave labor in its munition factories.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka I was thinking of Nazi slave labor more as a counter-example, with a higher rate of intentionally defective munitions, but that's anecdotal.

Comment: @DKNguyen For the flintlock era, powder *is* ammo.  Powder and shot is all you need.  Shot is easy, lead isn't hard to mine.  Powder is easy enough Europe learned to make it by hearing about it via traders who'd visited China.  Then they improved it over a period of centuries, but what they made in the 14th century worked.

Comment: To steal, to smuggle, and to *use up*

Answer (score 4):

## If mostly willing indentured servants, who like their lives, yes.

Being a prisoner doesn't make you any less able to make stuff. Slaves can certainly manufacture stuff.

## If they are brutally treated slaves it's a bad idea.

Slaves with guns can rebel and kill their masters.

Being a slave doesn't make you less able to make stuff.

Comment: Only with ammo.  The real danger is their being slack.  Which could get you just as dead,  but differently.

Comment: can have slaves at various locations make components, which are then assembled into the finished product by free people at the final stage. That way the slaves never have everything needed to produce working weapons.

Comment: The slaves would still be able to sabotage the product.

Comment: @Mary  first, ammo is much easier to obtain and hide than long guns are.  More importantly, you cannot test the quality of a firearm without firing it.  And an unskilled slave will *never* become a skilled artisan if they cannot test the quality of their own work.

Comment: But the gun lasts.   Ammo does not

Comment: https://www.survivalistboards.com/threads/black-powder-storage-lifespan.248866/

Comment: A slave who keeps his ammo on the shelf is a slave who has no ammo to shoot you.

Answer (score 3):

The Ottoman empire had a very strong artillery, made out of the cannons built by their [Ungarian underlings](https://www.historyanswers.co.uk/medieval-renaissance/ottoman-super-cannon-the-bombard-that-built-an-empire/) at the end of middle age.

The key point is that you need to provide sufficient reward and incentive for doing this, meaning not only letting them live to the end of the day. So, rather then "slaves", you better treat them as "highly skilled immigrants".

Comment: the gun in question was made around 1400, making it barely medieval, and could not be fired without powder, to which the metal casters had no access to.

Comment: It's less about the danger such a trained individual poses, but rather the sheer degree of skill required, and the motivation for said indentured individual to earnestly embrace the craft. This isn't the issue with munitions factories in Vichy France, but rather more like the issue with palatial eunuchs.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the Tredegar Iron Works in Richmond, Virginia was one of the most important factories in the CSA.

https://www.nps.gov/articles/tred.htm

> By the beginning of the Civil War in 1861, half of the 900 workers were slaves, including many in skilled positions.[5] By 1860, Anderson's father-in-law Dr. Robert Archer had joined the business and Tredegar became a leading iron producer in the country.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tredegar_Iron_Works#Management_under_Joseph_Reid_Anderson_(1841_%E2%80%93_Civil_War)

> Its wartime production included the iron plating for the first Confederate ironclad warship, the CSS Virginia which fought in the historic Battle of Hampton Roads in March 1862; credit for approximately 1,100 artillery pieces during the war, about half of the South's total domestic production of artillery during the war years of 1861–1865, including the development of the Brooke rifle;[4] a giant rail-mounted siege cannon. The company also manufactured railroad steam locomotives in the same period.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tredegar_Iron_Works#American_Civil_War

So apparently a weapons factory can operate ehere a significant fraction of the workers are slaves, and in a conflict where the specific goal the weapons are produced for is to keep the slaves - including the slave workers in the factory -  enslaved.

Comment: Tour example was *after* the invention of mass production. OP asked whether it was possible 100+ years before it.

Comment: @StephenS OP's question has multiple facets: whether "mass production" is possible in the 16th/17th century, and whether arms-production is feasible with slaves.  This example only comments upon the latter... but it absolutely shows a real historical precedent.

Answer (score 1):

*The Chosen* by S. M. Stirling, showed guns and other military equipment being manufactured by state-owned slaves in factories. The tech level shown was roughly 1920s-30s. This worked for the state that did it, in the short term, but eventually contributed to its downfall.

I agree that with artisanal production the use of slaves does not really gain mass production. Artisans must be trained and trusted, and treated at least somewhat well. Only if something like interchangeable parts is introduced does one gain mass production.

There were some slaves used in what was essentially factory work to produce military equipment during the US Civil War but this of course is at a tech level  significantly higher than the question proposes.